# Spark Python/SQL - how to group with unique combinations

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a 2 column Spark dataframe with unique combinations looking like this (simple version):

```
col1    col2
   a       b
   b       c
   b       d
   d       e
   f       g
```

I would like to form groups, in this case there would be 2 groups: (a,b,c,d,e) and (f,g) as these are linked through the combinations. The easiest way to count the number of members of the group would be if I could get this as an output:

```
col1    col2
   a       b
   a       c
   a       d
   a       e
   f       g
```

Does anyone know how to get to this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into graphs with pyspark and use `connectedComponents()` which will show groupings.